# What is the best way to design the api for a website using Ajax calls?

Tags: ajax, web-services, design-patterns, web-applications

I have a web application that has some web forms that submit the full form and the back end uses that to make the necessary modifications. I am starting to add a number of capabilities to allow inline editing of certain portions of data. These are ending up being really fine grain methods on my back end that don't feel quite right. I have basically been creating a backend method for each piece of data. Is there a more generic pattern that people are using for this?

Comment: links to papers, articles or books would be great here as well.

Answer (score 0):

I liked the OReilly book "RESTFul Web Services" by Leonard Richardson and Sam Ruby. http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596529260.do

Good explanation of Rest-iness, and some well-formed and enthusiastically-presented opinions on good/bad rest/nonrest web service API designs.